# Eclipse sans font is not readable

Tags: fonts, eclipse

**Ubuntu 12.04**, **Oracle Java 7**, **Eclipse Indigo/Juno**. Have following trouble (Same in code for final member names and static methods):

[image]

Font seems like **sans**, tried to change it to **Bitstream Sans**, no changes. 
How to make it clear?

**PS**: I've changed all occurancies of Sans font, but it still looks same. And after all I would like to figure out and solve problem, not just remove symptoms. I've tried both 1.7 and 1.6 Oracle Java.

Answer (score 0):

You can modify the font here : `Window` > `Preferences` > `General` > `Appearance` > `Colors and Fonts`.

Comment: I've tried this. Updated question.